# Problemas con Visual Studio para crear aplicaciones

Tags: android-studio, visual-studio-2015

Hace poco instalé Visual Studio 2017 en mi ordenador para trabajar con Android en C# y funcionaba a la  perfección, pues la app de Hola mundo po defecto que viene la ejecuté y la lanzó normal. Un día después instalé Android Studio para trabajar en ambos IDE's y ahora que quiero ejecutar mis apps en VS no me deja. Pues dice que hay un error de compilación.
Mi pregunta es

¿Tiene que ver con Android Studio el que no me pueda trabajar bien VS? 
Les agradecería mucho su ayuda.

Comment: ¿Qué error arroja a la hora de compilar? Muestranos el output.

Comment: Es este el error que me envía:

Comment: Por favor [edita la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/62893/edit) para agregar más información al respecto.

Comment: "Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto."
Y lo peor es que no me die en qué línea de código está ni en que archivo.

Comment: Disculpa si no pude enviar captura de pantalla, pero no me deja.